# how to write into file after doing sudo vi /dir to file

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10, vi

i have ubuntu 10.10 installed on a box.
and i ssh to it from another computer.

when i do sudo vi /var/www/page.php

i enter a text editor. when when i try to type i hear that ding noise as in i cant type. what do i press to allow me to start typing? when i type :q that works and it quits it. but what allows me to start typing? thanks

Comment: Matt Jenkin's list is a good primer but if things work out too difficult, use 'nano' instead. Its probably a lot closer to the text editors your used to. Instead of writing 'vi file', write 'nano file'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vi is what is known as a *modal* editor - that means it has a number of modes in which it operates.

When you first start vi it is in *command* mode.  Some common command mode key sequences:

- :q - Quit
- :q! - Force quit
- :w - Write file
- :wq! - Forced write file and exit
- :w /path/to/my/new/file - Write to a new file
- :r /path/to/file - read file and insert into buffer

To switch into one of the editing modes:

- i - Enter insert mode infront of the current character
- r - Replace single character
- R - Enter replace mode
- a - Enter insert mode after the current character
- A - Enter insert mode at the end of the current line
- o - Open a new line below cursor and enter insert mode
- O - Open a new line above cursor and enter insert mode

To return to *command* mode just press <kbd>Esc</kbd>

There are a huge number of other keypresses in *command* mode - [this list](http://www.sharpened.net/resources/commands/vi) is pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

type `a` to append or `i` to insert
Refer this [document](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html) for  more commands